# Creating Dummy Vatiables in R analytics

Tags: r, statistics, analytics, dummy-variable

i have a dataset for predicting the values that store will open in a certain area or not. I am confused to create dummy variables and want to know how to create dummies for variables Id,sales0,sales1,sales2,sales3,sales4,country,cosub,and many...if possible recommend me how to do that.....

Answer (score 1):

You can use the {dummy} package

```
> library(dummy)
> df <- data.frame(name = c("A", "B", "B", "C", "D", "E", "E", "E"))
> dummy(df)
  name_A name_B name_C name_D name_E
1      1      0      0      0      0
2      0      1      0      0      0
3      0      1      0      0      0
4      0      0      1      0      0
5      0      0      0      1      0
6      0      0      0      0      1
7      0      0      0      0      1
8      0      0      0      0      1
> cbind(df, dummy(df))
  name name_A name_B name_C name_D name_E
1    A      1      0      0      0      0
2    B      0      1      0      0      0
3    B      0      1      0      0      0
4    C      0      0      1      0      0
5    D      0      0      0      1      0
6    E      0      0      0      0      1
7    E      0      0      0      0      1
8    E      0      0      0      0      1
```